# jQuery Delay Time

Tags: jquery, delay

Can I do this to increase the time:

```
delay(10000*10)
```

Comment: what do you need to do exactly, regardless of the ability to get this peace of code to work.

Comment: Have you tried it? Is it not working for you?

Comment: Please clarify; there is no function called delay() in javascript. If it's user defined, I suppose you can just add another zero to either number?

Comment: @Andre ~ `.delay()` is a jQuery function. :)

Comment: well I want to increase the delay time, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Richard But technically it's a method of a jQuery object, but he's trying to run it as a function. Plus I didn't see he said jQuery. Also I still think the question needs clarification.

Comment: @Andre ~ you're right about it being seemingly run as a stand-alone function, but I'd have to argue that he did tag the question as "jquery" :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not just try it :)
http://jsfiddle.net/utj6h/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, assuming you are using some type of function that handles the delay I use something similar to the following (to set a Refresh Rate, which is stored in the Session):

```
setInterval(function ()
{
    var grid = $('#GridName').data('tGrid');
    grid.ajaxRequest();
}, <%= int.Parse(Session["RefreshRate"].ToString())*1000 %>);
```

so for your usage:

```
setInterval(function ()
{
    //Refresh logic

}, (10000*10)); //Your delay goes here
```

**Delay function:**

```
var delay = (function(){
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
    })();
```

**Edit:** Totally neglected the jQuery [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function, which should be working as you have written. If not, it may not like the calculation inside the argument and you could try:

```
var delay = 10000*10;

.delay(delay)
```